# Can't remove title area of AppBar

Tags: android, flutter

android stuidio 3.6

```
class MainScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(title: new Text("Title")),
        body: new SingleChildScrollView(
            child: new Container(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.only(
          left: Constants.DEFAULT_MARGIN,
          top: Constants.DEFAULT_MARGIN,
          right: Constants.DEFAULT_MARGIN),
              child: new Text("text"),
    )));
  }
}
```

result
[image]

How remove part of AppBar where show **Title** ? Only this part. Status bar must stay.

Comment: I don’t understand... can you make a mockup picture of what you’re trying to archive

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your `body: SingleChildScrollView()` with `SafeArea` and remove `appBar`. Please read about [SafeArea here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SafeArea-class.html).

```
Scaffold(
  body: SafeArea(child: SingleChildScrollView(child: /*...*/))
)
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understand the question correctly, you can remove the title from the appbar by omitting the title paremeter:

```
class MainScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        body: new SingleChildScrollView(
            child: new Container(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.only(
          left: Constants.DEFAULT_MARGIN,
          top: Constants.DEFAULT_MARGIN,
          right: Constants.DEFAULT_MARGIN),
              child: new Text("text"),
    )));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just get rid of the title text but keep the appbar, you can do this:

```
     class MainScreen extends StatelessWidget {
     @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return new Scaffold(
  appBar: new AppBar(),
    body: new SingleChildScrollView(
        child: new Container(
  margin: const EdgeInsets.only(
      left: Constants.DEFAULT_MARGIN,
      top: Constants.DEFAULT_MARGIN,
      right: Constants.DEFAULT_MARGIN),
          child: new Text("text"),
)));
   }
   }
```

If you want to just get rid of the title text and the appbar, you can do this:

```
     class MainScreen extends StatelessWidget {
     @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return new Scaffold(

    body: new SingleChildScrollView(
        child: new Container(
  margin: const EdgeInsets.only(
      left: Constants.DEFAULT_MARGIN,
      top: Constants.DEFAULT_MARGIN,
      right: Constants.DEFAULT_MARGIN),
          child: new Text("text"),
)));
   }
   }
```